# Не могу получить объект DOMRect в рамках теста Webdriver-io (js)

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, dom, selenium-webdriver

Мне нужно получить координаты элемента на веб-странице с помощью функции .getBoundingClientRect(). Когда я решал эту задачу год назад, то делал это так:

```
browser.executeScript('window.document.querySelector("div.myDiagramDiv canvas").getBoundingClientRect();', [])
```

**Примечание:** данную операцию я выполняю в рамках написания автоматизированного теста на Webdriver-io, поэтому объект *window* недоступен, и приходится пользоваться *browser.executeScript*.

Сейчас, спустя год, я вернулся к своей задаче, и код, приведенный выше, возвращает пустой объект.

Я пробовал продебажить этот код в рамках теста и в консоли браузера. Результат следующий:

**Код теста Webdriver-io:**

```
a = browser.executeScript('window.document.querySelector("div.myDiagramDiv canvas")', [])
console.log(a) # вывод: { 'element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf': 'ELEMENT-40' }
b = browser.executeScript('window.document.querySelector("div.myDiagramDiv canvas").getBoundingClientRect();', [])
console.log(b) # вывод: {}
```

**Дебаг в консоли браузера**

```
a = window.document.querySelector("div.my_diagram_div canvas")
# вывод: <canvas tabindex="0" style="position: absolute; top:…t: 435px; cursor: auto;" width="1519" height="435">
b = a.getBoundingClientRect()
# вывод: DOMRect { x: 158.5, y: 132, width: 1519, height: 435, top: 132, right: 1677.5, bottom: 567, left: 158.5 }
```

Скрин консоли браузера:
[image: Скрин консоли браузера]

Почему в рамках теста я не могу получить объект DOMRect, а в консоли браузера это получается?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо

```
elem.getBoundingClientRect()
```

нужно использовать

```
elem.getWindowRect()
```

*.getWindowRect()* есть в спецификации **Webdriver-io**, поэтому *browser.executeScript()* больше не нужен.